# Postgres - Create or replace table

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I have a table that is already created with data and I need only modify the schema to add some constraints .

my created tabled schema

```
CREATE TABLE public.note (
    note_id bigint  NOT NULL,
    confidential boolean NOT NULL,
    follow_up_date date,
    notification_date date,
    priority integer NOT NULL,
    recurring_follow_up_interval interval,
    status character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    create_date timestamp with time zone,
    deleted boolean NOT NULL,
    last_modified_date timestamp with time zone,
    time_spent integer,
    title text,
    version bigint  NOT NULL,
    assigned_to_id bigint,
    note_category_id bigint NOT NULL,
    created_by_id bigint,
    last_modified_by_id bigint
);
```

what I need to match

```
 create table note
(
    note_id                      bigint  default nextval('note_id_seq'::regclass) not null,
    confidential                 boolean                                          not null,
    follow_up_date               date,
    notification_date            date,
    priority                     integer default 0                                not null,
    recurring_follow_up_interval interval,
    status                       varchar(255)                                     not null,
    create_date                  timestamp with time zone,
    deleted                      boolean default false                            not null,
    last_modified_date           timestamp with time zone,
    time_spent                   integer,
    title                        text,
    version                      bigint  default 0                                not null,
    assigned_to_id               bigint,
    note_category_id             bigint                                           not null,
    created_by_id                bigint,
    last_modified_by_id          bigint,
    constraint note_pkey
        primary key (note_id),
    constraint fk_4nrhbn2j8j2vqqh78vleef9xr
        foreign key (created_by_id) references admin_user,
    constraint fk_eid7x7jfvjoe1h5tnyouhmqpa
        foreign key (assigned_to_id) references admin_user,
    constraint fk_oi5l4dg3sg5ep5neagmvp9r7o
        foreign key (note_category_id) references note_category,
    constraint fk_tk8ncyc0hmdi3gfh67b4jyu3l
        foreign key (last_modified_by_id) references admin_user
);
```

as you can see it missing all defaults + all constraint to the other tables

any way to copy the intended schema to the created one without loosing the data

I am using Postgres 12

**UPDATE**

I know I could use alter to modify some columns but it will be a long process for me as there are many columns and I got more than 300 tables that have the same case

I manually alter one column to add sequence but I need easier way to do that for all columns

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY note ALTER COLUMN note_id SET DEFAULT nextval('note_id_seq'::regclass);
```

Comment: See [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html). Short version, you can change the table in place.

Comment: it will be a long process I will update my question to include my tries

Comment: If you already have the desired schema (with empty tables) you can import the data into it using the output from `pg_dump --data-only` -n old_schema

Comment: Then something like: `create table schema as table_name_new, insert into table_name_new  select * from table_name, alter table table_name rename to table_name_old, alter table_name_new rename to table_name`. This assumes the column types an order stay the same and columns are not added or deleted. Also until you drop old table you will have double the amount of data. There is also the issue of making sure you do tables that have FK relationships in correct order.

Comment: If you already have the desired schema, and the tables in the two schemas/databases are identical (apart from the indexes and constrants)  , you could use `pg_dump --schema-only -n ` on the database+schema where this DDL lives and use the resulting script to update/fix the target database/schema. pg_dump generates DDL in a usable partial order. You can first edit out the `CREATE TABLE` statements, and the setval('sequence') statements. [make sure you have a backup of your precious data]